# Factoring a polynomial with complex roots

Tags: polynomials, factoring, cubics

Can someone just check if this method and calculations are correct?  Task is: Let $P(x) = -5+a+2x+ax^2+7x^3$ and $x=-\frac{1}{2}$ is its zero. Find other zeros and factorise the polynomial.

I solved the equation $P(-\frac{1}{2})=0$ and got that $a= \frac{11}{2}$. Now,   $P(x) = -5+\frac{11}{2}+2x+\frac{11}{2}x^2+7x^3 = \frac{1}{2}+2x+\frac{11}{2}x^2+7x^3 $.

Then, I divided P(x) by $(x+\frac{1}{2})$ so $P(x)=(x+\frac{1}{2})(7x^2+2x+1) =(x+\frac{1}{2})(7x^2+2x+1)  $

Now, $7x^2+2x+1$ has complex roots: $-1+ i\sqrt{6} $ and $-1- i\sqrt{6} $,  so 
$P(x) =(x+\frac{1}{2})(x- (-1+ i\sqrt{6})) (x- (-1-i\sqrt{6}))$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did go the $7$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac12+2x+\frac{11}2x^2+7x^3 =7(x+\frac12)(x-\frac{−1+i\sqrt{6}}{7})(x-\frac{−1-i\sqrt{6}}{7})$